# Atom's beautify package not installing

Tags: atom-editor, atom-beautify

I am using atom editor on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and the beautify package was working fine. Then, I tried to update it and it failed. So, I tried to uninstall it and reinstall using the package manager in the atom text editor and this error showed up:

```
Installing “atom-beautify@0.33.0” failed.Hide output…

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated @types/commander@2.12.2: This is a stub types definition for commander (https://github.com/tj/commander.js). commander provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/commander installed!
npm WARN deprecated jscs-preset-wikimedia@1.0.1: Deprecated in favour of eslint-config-wikimedia. -- https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T118941
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/suraj/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/suraj/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-11882-11505-6pr0wo.9rpchumcxr/package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.7.15" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EREADFILE

npm ERR! Error extracting /home/suraj/.atom/.apm/marko/4.13.3/package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/suraj/.atom/.apm/marko/4.13.3/package.tgz'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-11882-11505-1xp4stp.i1sk7yzaor/npm-debug.log
```

Later, I tried to install it manually over the terminal using these commands:

```
cd /home/my_username/.atom/.apm/marko
apm install atom-beautify
```

And this error showed up:

```
Installing atom-beautify to /home/suraj/.atom/packages ✗

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated @types/commander@2.12.2: This is a stub types definition for commander (https://github.com/tj/commander.js). commander provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/commander installed!
npm WARN deprecated jscs-preset-wikimedia@1.0.1: Deprecated in favour of eslint-config-wikimedia. -- https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T118941
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/suraj/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/suraj/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-11882-10844-9qhjii.bzpnuhm2t9/package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.7.15" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EREADFILE

npm ERR! Error extracting /home/suraj/.atom/.apm/marko/4.13.3/package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/suraj/.atom/.apm/marko/4.13.3/package.tgz'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-11882-10844-lpmvk7.f7mbo6r/npm-debug.log
```

Please help

Comment: This is a [know issue](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/2217) with `atom-beautify`. Have you tried installing an older version (e.g. ` apm install atom-beautify@0.32.5`) to see if it fixes that. Aside from that, please note that Stack Overflow is for questions on coding, not general software support. Please ask on https://askubuntu.com or https://superuser.com instead!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .apm folder and install the packages again after a restart of Atom.